# How many bits does the key value in this hash function use?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the hash function

```
size_t hash(char *str)
{
  return *str & 47;
}
```

> How many bits of the key value does this hash function use?

I am a bit confused what is meant by this question. Shouldn't the answer also depend on the size of `str`?

Comment: I, too, am confused by what is meant by this question. What are you asking exactly? Are you asking how many bits are in `size_t`? The answer is simply `sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Maybe the answer is 5, ie the number of set bits in 47? Any other bits of the input are necessarily ignored. Not very clear though.

Comment: @Human-Compiler It was a multiple choice question that I saw with the possible answers 1,2,5,6,8,47. I honestly have no idea what the question is asking.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I slightly edited the question to make it verbatim.

Comment: The hash function takes the first character of str and checks if bits 1, 2, 3, 4 or 6 are set.  So it is checking 5 bits out of the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

> I am a bit confused what is meant by this question.

The quoted question is poorly worder in my opinion. But, I assume that they intend to ask "How many bits of input affect the return value of this hash function".

> Shouldn't the answer also depend on the size of str?

If you mean "length of the string", then a good hash function would take all bits of an input string into consideration. But this hash function doesn't, so the answer to the question doesn't depend on the length.

It does depend on how many bits are in `char`.

Comment: I slightly edited the OP to reflect the verbatim wording. Is it any clearer or still confusing? Still reads as confusing to me.

Comment: @westcoaststudent Yes, the edited quote is still poorly worder in my opinion.